# Two versions of .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I'm looking to move my site to https and I need to add a rule to the .htaccess file to set up the 301 redirect. I have read a lot of guides for this and there seem to be many different possibilities, but two of them keep coming up over and over again.

Why are these two options different?  What do they do differently?

Option 1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Option 2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time there are different ways to achieve one's goal, an answer to which method is the best can be opinion b(i)ased.

Option 1

- will redirect all non-SSL traffic, independently of the listening ports you are requesting (you can listen to several ports at the same time, like 80, 81,..)
- will redirect any FQDN to its https equivalent, keeping the request URI. You don't need to adapt it, unless you want several FQDNs to be redirected to the same https site.
- the return code being 301, it will be cached easily by any proxy

Option 2

- will redirect only traffic coming to the 80 port. If you are listening to another port, which is very likely on huge hosting platforms particularly behind load-balancers, you will need to change from 80 to another value
- will redirect any FQDN to the very same https site (www.yoursite.com), keeping the request URI.
- the return code being 302, it will probably be not cached if other headers are not set (Cache-Control)

Option 1 requires less work for the administrator and I believe it is the most used of the two. If there is any performance difference between the two, it's probably neglibible though I believe that Option 1 is better because %{REQUEST_URI} is a server variable and is not extracted from a regex.